# Installing a document class

Tags: installing, document-classes

I'm supposed to "install jT.cls" but I don't know what this means.  I'm sure this has answers already, but unfortunately I can't read them - I don't know what too many of the terms mean.

I'm guessing I'm going to get answers telling me "this is explained here [link]" and then I'm not going to understand that link.  I don't understand what "directory" or "source" files mean.  I can open my MikTex and I can find the files ending in ".tex" on my computer so that I can open them.  More I don't really know.

I've understood I'm supposed to put *some* file *somewhere* but I don't know what "put the file" means (or even which file?) or where *somewhere* is.

Thanks in advance and apologies for my ignorace/stupidity.

Comment: The simplest solution to get you going is to put it in the same folder as your `.tex` document.  When you're a bit more comfortable, here's the unreadable link you ask for. :) [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063)

Comment: put what? (but i think i know where)  i don't understand in what sense "jT.cls" is a thing.

Comment: Well it should be a file that you downloaded from somewhere,  I assume.  Presumably here: https://jtnb.math.u-bordeaux.fr/jT.cls So just save this file into the folder where you will write your document and it should work.

Comment: i'm to follow instructions that say "download jT.cls".  i can click on "jT.cls" and i get something that looks like a latex file/code.  i've tried copying and pasting it into a new document but it doesn't play (i don't get an error, it just pauses mid-play).  did you mean that this should theoretically compile and i should put this new document's latex file with my .tex document?

Comment: Save the `jT.cls` file, don't try to do anything else with it and create a new document `myfile.tex` which will begin with `\documentclass{jT}`.

Comment: what is the file?  is it a new .tex file which has exactly the contents of that link copied and pasted into it?  or is it something else?

if the first one, i've saved it (as jT.cls, so the whole name of the file is jT.cls.tex) and put it in the folder "my documents" which is the folder that contains all my files which are .tex files.  (but creating a new document with your command still doesn't work, so obviously i've misunderstood something)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126315/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-user208878).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved via chat and was fundamentally a problem with Windows.